# iTunes Album Artwork not available in all Sizes

Tags: windows-7, itunes

I used iTunes and everything worked fine until today. When I try to display Large / Medium artwork, not all the artworks are displayed. However, when I try to display the small artworks, everything works.

### Large (buggy):

[image]

### Small (normal):

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Tech Specs: iTunes on Windows 7 x64, v. 10.3.1. All the artworks are stored locally on my hard drive (.jpg files (i added them manually)).

Comment: I do the same thing and I do not have any problems with the display size. All my Album Art are sized to 300x300 pixel dimensions. So I would check to see if the Album artwork you are trying to display has smaller dimensions than those that display. Also when did you upgrade to 10.3.1? Maybe the upgrade broke your iTunes.

Comment: actually i recently updated to 10.3.1. is there a way to downgrade?

Comment: not sure. but you could download an older version and try running it. http://www.oldapps.com/itunes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is other: The artwork shows ONLY when album contains MORE THAN 6 TRACKS. When an album contains less than 6 tracks, the artwork is not displayed.